# Port 80 refused by Linux (Ubunt 12.04)

Tags: apache-httpd, tcp, http

I am having an issue I cannot seem to resolve.  I am being refused only on port 80.  However port 8080, and 22 (Tomcat and ssh) are available.  I am pretty sure this is not an Apache thing, however I cannot be 100%.  Temporarily I have disabled firewall to eliminate that via `sudo ufw disable`.  Here are some of my outputs:

**sudo iptables -L -n**

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

**netstat -nao | grep 80**

```
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      off (0.00/0/0)
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8005          :::*                    LISTEN      off (0.00/0/0)
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     8180
```

**netstat | less**

```
Active Internet connections (w/o servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0     48 xx.xxx.xxx.102:ssh      67.xxx.xxx.4.ptr.:40726 ESTABLISHED
Active UNIX domain sockets (w/o servers)
Proto RefCnt Flags       Type       State         I-Node   Path
unix  5      [ ]         DGRAM                    7416     /dev/log
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     8181     
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     8180     
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    10399    
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    6992     
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     6959     /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     6958     
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    8942     
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     6870     @/com/ubuntu/upstart
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     9273     
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     8603     /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     8602     
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     6754     
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     6753     
unix  3      [ ]         DGRAM                    8452     
unix  3      [ ]         DGRAM                    8451     
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     8418     @/com/ubuntu/upstart
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     8415
```

I even went so far as to purge and remove apache2   ...  In hopes it would reset the listening on port 80.  I really have no idea where else to go ..  Does anyone have any suggestions where to look next?

## EDIT

OK .. So Apache is not starting ..  Now to figure out why .. `/var/log/apach2/error.log` shows no errors since last server reboot, and here is the result of `configtest`

**sudo apachectl configtest**

```
Syntax OK
```

Comment: Are you sure apache was running? `ps aux | grep apache` or `service apache2 status`

Comment: Good call ..  Apache is NOT running ..  However logs don't show any errors on startup?!  Will update question above with pertinent info ..

Comment: Did you try starting it manually? `service httpd start`.

Comment: Of course ..  `* Starting web server apache2` ...  However the return of `service apache2 status` is `Apache2 is NOT running.`

Comment: That's `sudo service httpd start`, right?

Comment: Are you using SELinux? You may need to `semanage port -a -t http_port_t -p tcp 80`

Answer (score 1):

You could try debugging Apache as it starts up with the following command:

```
$ sudo strace -Ff apachectl start
```

You could also do this:

```
$ sudo strace -Ff service httpd start
```

To catch the output to a log file:

```
$ sudo strace -Ff service httpd start 2>&1 | tee apache_$(date +%F_%T).log
```